# Changing UIColor of the buttonImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uiimage, uicolor

I have a `UIImage` of `redColor` but I want to show it in `whiteColor`, how can it be done? Here is my code for:

```
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"close-button.png"];
UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[aButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
aButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,
                           0.0, 
                           buttonImage.size.width,
                           buttonImage.size.height);

UIBarButtonItem *aBarButtonItem = 
  [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:aButton];

[aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didSelectBackButton:) 
               forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:aBarButtonItem];
```

Comment: your question is not clear , when you need to change the button color on White, if it is normal else user click the event on that time

Comment: the default color should be white colored.

Comment: you can set uiimage and background color red?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the `UIColor` of an `UIImage` use this method inside an `interface` of `UIImage`:

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, NO, self.scale);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height);
    CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, self.CGImage);
    [color setFill];
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
UIImageView *icon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 40)];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
icon.image = [img imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
icon.tintColor = tintColor;
icon.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

Comment: i tried this but its not working, still the image is red colored, i checked it in debug view.
My navigation bar is red colored and my image is also red colored, thats the reason i want the close button having white color.

Comment: did you try changing the nav bar's `tintColor`?

Answer (score 0):

**Just add image using renderingMode and later set tint colour.**
Also the background and any portion of the image that you do not wish to render using the tint color must be completely transparent.

https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/ios-7-tutorial-series-tint-color-and-easy-app-theming

```
UIImage *buttonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"close-button.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];

[aButton setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```